# Export PowerShell prompt to remote session

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I want to customize my PowerShell prompt to my personal preference. After following the information provided by the Microsoft docs I finally ended up with a satisfying result.
Then I opened a remote session and the prompt was not loaded during the remote session. Instead the default one was used.
My question now is whether there's a possability of exporting the local prompt to a PowerShell remote session (to every computer). What's interesting in my opinion is that the remote session to my own computer also didn't load the globally configured prompt on my computer. Also I want to know whether (and how) you can customize this remote prompt if there's a special possability (e.g. define a function like `remote-prompt {...}` to configure the PSRemoting prompt) for this, provided that you do need (or can) export the local prompt.
The official docs to customize the prompt only explained local things like nesting which are not working by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do something with [PowerShell Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7).

Also you can change the look and feel from your PowerShell by changing the `$host.UI.RawUI` parameters. Eg. `$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Installing some stuff..."`, `$host.ui.RawUI.WindowSize=(New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(1024,768)`, `$host.ui.RawUI.ForeGroundColor = "red"`, etc...

Comment: The command the site metioned to export your current profile is the following: `Invoke-Command -Session $s -FilePath $PROFILE`. But in case your profile isn't the user configured (whose path is inside the `$PROFILE` variable) you have to manually replace it with your profile path. The only thing I couldn't change at the moment (with this information provided) is the prepended `[localhost] ...`.